# Use of generic method with primitive return type

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Util<K,V> {
    public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
    }
}
```

I know why we are using `Util<K,V>` but what is the use of `static <K,V>` ?.I got this from [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html). Please help me to understand.

Comment: For static generic methods, the type parameter section must appear before the method's return type. Thats the reason otherwise you need to only specify the return type.

Comment: The code at the link has `Util` with no `<K,V>`.

Comment: That one was added by me intentionally to differentiate and make question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate this. `<K, V>` are method parameters. `static` is a modifier that makes method "static", i.e. you can invoke it without creating object.

Just read something about java, methods, classes, static methods etc.

Comment: why we need to add static <K,V> boolean,because which is same as static boolean ?

Comment: <K, V> are not method parameters. The method parameters are `p1` and `p2`. Yes, you know that, but it makes the answer less useful because it's unclear to a beginner who does not already know that.

Answer (score 2):

A static method is called on its own, without reference to any instance of the `Util` class. Since only *instances* of `Util` have the class's type parameters bound, the type parameters used in `compare` are left unbound. Therefore the mechanism of *type inference* must be invoked to resolve them at each call site. This is what the `<K, V>` syntax in front of method return type represents.

Note that an instance method can also use unbound type parameters, so `static` is not the essence of your question. It just happens that most methods which rely on type inference are static.

Answer (score 1):

static methods can be called on class without a need to instantiate an object

stolen from [here](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Static-Method.htm)

Normally you can't call a method of a class without first creating an instance of that class. By declaring a method using the static keyword, you can call it without first creating an object because it becomes a class method (i.e. a method that belongs to a class rather than an object).

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword has nothing to do with `Util<K,V>`, it is only to make the method a class method, so that you do not need to create an instance of the class in order to call the method.